# make dynamic webpage from html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a webpage that retrieves data (via ajax/php) and shows it in an html div (`id='parent'`). I'd like to add a print feature, which will take the contents of `parent` and show it in another page.

I've never made a dynamic webpage before. All the information I show is just pulled onto the main page via ajax. So I don't know where to begin really. I assume it has something to do with those long character strings I see in the urls of lots of internet sites, but I don't know! do I just use the url character string to store information about the current state of the page so the user can go back to what they were looking at with the back button. will the back button automatically work, or do i have to listen for it and reload the page based on what i pull from that string?

Very appreciative if someone can point me to some good articles or work out a little pattern of what steps I should take to

1. pull data from the page
2. put it on another page (or is it another page? do I just clear the page i'm on and re-fill it with other data??)
3. enable the back button to go back to the first page.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are pulling data via php, then you already have a dynamic page, dynamic simply means that the content is not hardcoded. However, I think what you probably need is a 'print stylesheet'. This is an extra stylesheet which doesn't affect the normal layout, but allows you to change the styles of elements when the page is printed (or print previewed). In your case you would simply set the visibility of all the other elements to invisible, and perhaps absolutely position the div you want to show at the top of the page.

Comment: ^Using this, people wouldn't have to go to another page, the page they are already on would look different when they printed it :)

Comment: What do you mean by "show it in another page"? what it this page?

Comment: @NicoBurns main page is a grid of multiple header items. clicking on one header item shows a small modal with details about. I'd like to have the print button replace everything on the page with just the content on that modal, so that the information can breathe a bit more, and only that specific information is available to print. The idea I'm sort of after is like an internet email interface. you see the message subject, you click it, you're taken to a page with the entire message.

Comment: @MitziMeow show the current info in the modal as a separate webpage.

Comment: @thomas Is there any chance a link to the live webpage? It would be much easier for us to give a more specific answer if we could see the actual code.

Comment: @MitziMeow Ugh..I wish. It's got all this sensitive data on it. I guess my question can be boiled down to basically this: what procedure would you use to show dynamic data on a new screen, and have the back button take you back to the main screen? .. >< don't know if that makes sense or is totally thorough..

Comment: @thomas, do you want encryption for ajax? I don't really understand what does the sensitive data matter. You use JS to take sensitive data from a page (ajax) and use JS again to make that data appear inside a div tag (like the code i posted as an answer), afterwards you can just open a windows and "document.write" that same data to it, will be a pop-up without having to use the back button.

Comment: @MitziMeow sensitive data just means my boss won't show the site online. i'm setting up a demo site with phony data now..

Comment: @MitziMeow do you still have time to look at a demo page?

Comment: @thomas you should just post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those long character strings you are talking about sound like SessionIDs. The idea is that you store all the data you need to share between website requests on the server and identify the user by this ID to retreive the correct dataset when she requests the next website.

PHP already supports this out-of-the-box. The documentation of the PHP session handling functionality can be found here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

To take data from ajax into another  tag you can do something like this

```
<script>
var page_request = false;

function ajax_request(url)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
        page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    { // if IE
        try
        {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    else
        return false

    page_request.open('GET', url);
    page_request.send(null);

    return page_request.responseText;
}

function ChangeDiv(id, url)
{
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML =  ajax_request(url);
}
</script>
```

then just call ChangeDiv with the url you want (e.g 'http://website.com/page.php?params=1')